# Log in to computer on same network for disk access

Tags: python, pygtk

Actually I want to access another computer's drive from my computer which is present in LAN. All LAN computers are password protected, then how to connect my computer to another computer and access drives using python code.

And I have scanning code, only I want to connect one computer to another LAN computer with login credentials and access its drives. Someone help me for this, I have not able to find a solution to this problem.

Update: System is Windows and I can't use other because I am creating app using python code

Comment: Please elaborate - are you on Windows, Unix/Linux/Mac...?

Comment: Does this require python? Many network access options like mounting the remote drive over NFS, using SAMBA, SSH or FTP have solved the problem of disk access with credentials.

Comment: @peterph System is Windows and i can't use other bcoz i am creating app using python code

Comment: Well, Python is multiplatform, so that really is not the a reason for using Windows. But that's not that important now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows, just attach whatever is needed as a network drive. If you want to do it in a script, use the Windows `net` command:

```
net use X: \\Server\directory /user:"DOMAIN\username" "password"
```

If you need to do it from Python, use `os.system()` to run the command as Mevin suggests in the comment below.

Comment: You can use the python function `os.system()` to execute this cmd command from python.This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python .

Comment: but what python code or script, i have to write for connecting one to another computer with credential. if you have any example or code, please share to me.

Comment: @AshishJain Read the question and the link Mevin kindly provided. If you need to learn Python, go to https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers or https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers.

Comment: Hi guys, I got python code which will connect one computer to another computer with credentials in LAN network. @peterph thanks for your suggestion but i didn't get from u.